# Differences in server settings between Heroku and Godaddy

Tags: php, heroku, runtime-error

I hosted a PHP web app with Heroku.

I've now moved this app to a GoDaddy server. The problem is that the server seems to throw alot more errors than Heroku.

As an example - if I have an `unassigned var` It will throw a warning but it won't show up to the user. On the other hand, if the site is hosted on GoDaddy, it will show these error messages on the client.

What is the toggle that I'd need to set to get rid of these warnings showing up on the client?

Answer (score 0):

You **should** use [isset()](http://php.net/isset) to check ensure variables are assigned.

---

***Disclaimer*** - following are not good practice and are posted for completeness only

Use [Error control operator](http://php.net/operators.errorcontrol)

```
// suppress everything from notifications to errors
@annoyingMethodCall();
```

Change [Error reporting level](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

```
// disable it altogether
error_reporting(0);
```